# ::before and ::after pseudo work when styled separately but not together. Why?

Tags: css

I wanna put to lines on the top and bottom of the nav buttons which I tend to transform later. I used ::after and ::before selectors but both of them showed up at the top even though I targeted ::after in an other line.
When I target the separately everything works as expected. Please tell me what did I miss.

Thanks!

```
enter code here

#navbar .type5 a::before,
#navbar .type5 a::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;  
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: var(--primary-light);
}
    
#navbar .type5 a::after {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset `top` for `::after`

```
#navbar .type5 a::before,
#navbar .type5 a::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;  
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: var(--primary-light);
}
    
#navbar .type5 a::after {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write your rulesets the way you write, you end up adding both `top: 0` and `bottom: 0` rules to your `a::after` element. That's probably why you're not getting the result you want. Maybe try separating them? Write `top` rule only for `::before` and `bottom` rule only for `::after`, and they can share the rest of the rules still.